# Forecast ARIMA and out of sample evaluation

Tags: r, time-series, forecasting, arima, model-evaluation

I have a train daily data and test daily data. I fit an ARIMA to my train data, forecast it 7 days and I want to get some performance measures of the forecasted values.

I can get performance measures of the trained fit by runnning `summary(fit)`
And I can plot the forecast against the test data with this code easily:
plot(forecast,
     main = 'ARIMA',
     xlab = 'Date',
     ylab = 'Number of patients',
     xlim = c(2017.75,2017.9))
lines(test_data, col = 'red', lty = 2)

But I can't find a way to evaluate the prediction. Tried using `accuracy(forecast, test_data)` but it returns an error: (this actually happens for all models I try running, what is the problem?)

```
Error in mean(actual != predicted) : 
  (list) object cannot be coerced to type 'integer'
In addition: Warning message:
In actual != predicted :
  longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length
```

Can you please help me?

Comment: Please provide reproducible code of the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was very stupid. 
I had installed both libraries `Metrics` and `forecast` and both have an `accuracy()` function.

The one I was looking for is the `forecast` one, but the `Metrics` one is the one I was actually using, hence the error.